# Invalid conversion from "char" to "char *"

Tags: c, function, switch-statement, character

This is the program to convert a Roman number (for example VI) to a decimal.
The algorithm is writing a function that recognize each element of the input string and return the corresponding value in decimal.

We got `char Roman_num[20]`
For each element,    `sum+=value(Roman_num[i])`.The function prototype is `int value (char digit)`.It results in the '**Invalid conversion from char to char *'** error.

However, when passing each element's address `&a[i]` to the function and changing the prototype to `int value (char *digit)`, it doesn't repeat this error but leads to another error in this switch-case (inside the function) :    `switch (*digit)` gives an error of **'digit' cannot appear in a constant-expression**

My question is I was not clear that: in this example, do we have to pass only the address to the funcion? If we want to pass the value, a single character value, then how? Last but not least, *digit is actually a single character, then why it cannot appear in a constant-expression in `case()`?

I will be grateful for your help. On the other hand, can you please recommend me some books for deep understanding in C? I'm now using **C : How To Program** book, and I hardly know about how the variables, functions working on the inside for a deeper understanding.

This is the code:

```
int value (char *digit);
int main (void)
{
    char a[100];
    int length,i,sum=0;
    printf("Enter your Roman number: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(a);
    printf("\nThe Roman number that you have entered is %s",a);
    length=strlen(a);
    for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        sum+=value(&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nthen it is: %d",sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int value (char *digit)
{
    int num;
    case ( *digit ){
        case 'M':
            num=1000;
            break;
        case 'D':
            num=500;
            break;
        case 'C':
            num=100;
            break;
        case 'L':
            num=50;
            break;
        case 'X':
            num=10;
            break;
        case 'V':
            num=5;
            break;
        case 'I':
            num=1;
            break;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a concise code sample that compiles and reproduces the problem? The only way I can see the first error is if your signature is `int value( char *digit )`.

Comment: We need to see actual code, not disjointed snippets. The problem is in something you haven't shown us.

Comment: Please post code.  We cannot help too much without the source in front of us.

Comment: `char Roman_num[20] For each element, sum+=value(Roman_num[i]).The function prototype is int value (char digit)` Error as they say in this case does not occur.

Comment: Wild guess: you wrote `switch case (*digit)` Visual Basic style.

Comment: I have posted it, as editted

Comment: please, reopen it, I have added the code

Answer (score 2):

Since you will not post code, here some code for getting roman numerals that always increase.  The subtraction part is left to you to figure out.  I only post this as it sounds like you are self teaching yourself which is comendable:

```
int romanToValue(const char c)
{
    switch(c)  // Only works with upper-case as lower case means different things.
    {
      case 'I' : return 1;
      case 'V' : return 5;
      case 'X' : return 10;
      case 'L' : return 50;
      case 'C' : return 100;
      case 'D' : return 500;
      case 'M' : return 1000;
      default: printf("Bad value in string %c\n", c); break;  
    }

    return 0;
}

int romanToInt(const char *str)
{
  int value = 0;
  int i;

  for(i=0; str[i]; i++)  // Dangerous way to do strings, but works for a C example.
  {
    value += romanToValue(str[i]);
  }

  return value;
}

int main(void)
{
  const char cstr[] = "VIII";

  printf("value:%d\n", romanToInt(cstr));
  return 0;
}
```

Notice the `switch` statement is working off of `char` values.

Comment: How is that a 'dangerous' way to do strings? As long as you're passed a NUL-terminated string there is no problems whatsoever.

Comment: I always like working off of known lengths instead of "assuming".  Truth is, anytime I work with C strings like this, I get a bit uneasy.

Comment: It's good pedagogical code but the algorithm is deficient. What about IX for example. Which should be 9 not 11? +1 though for nice answer.

Comment: As I stated, the subtraction part is left to him.  I just wanted to get a code sample up there that showed how to use a switch statement in a situation close to what he was working in.

Comment: @Bathsheba: We use an if-selection: if entered_string[strlen[entered_string]-2]=='I' then sum-=2. The right-most digit in Roman number located at (string length -1), so the second right-most, which  means 'I' in the string 'IV', is at (string length -2)
If that location is 'I', then we subtract the sum by 2

Comment: @Michael Dorgan: since switch is working off of char values, there is no way to handle the char value ( the character we read and store as a variable ) ?

Comment: Nguyen - you don't want to do it like that! You should implement a BNF grammar for Roman numerals. Much more satisfying. Professionally we'd use a third party library but that takes the fun out of it.

Comment: Not sure I understand either comment nor the down-vote?  As stated, I didn't want to add code to show how to handle IIVVXX type numbers where you have to subtract as it would give away the rest of the problem.  And I don't understand the char value question/comment either.  Days old now so moving on I guess.