# strcpy() and strcat() giving errors in initialization & conversion. in C

Tags: c

1. invalid conversion from `const char` to `const char*` ,
2. initializing argument 2 of `char* strcpy(char*, const char*)` ,
3. invalid conversion from `const char` to `const char*` ,
4. initializing argument 2 of `char* strcat(char*, const char*)`.

```c
void subString(char s[])
{

 char *sub;
 char newS;
 sub=s;
 strcpy(newS,sub[0]);
 strcat(newS,sub[1]);
 printf("%s\n",newS);
 return;
}
```

Please answer in terms of C language.

let s="abab"

Comment: What are the other values?

Comment: And `newS` is a char, as well.

Comment: `char newS[strlen(s)*2];...strcpy(newS,sub+0); strcat(newS,sub+1);`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid conversion from "char" to "char \*"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739940/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-char)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It does work. but printing newS is giving garbage values at first two positions.

Comment: Ah, your problem is that the Rosetta Code "String append" task has no C solution, right? http://rosettacode.org/wiki/String_append   Learn C and write one.

Comment: @user3907718 do you want `"ab"`? also do you do `sub=s;`?

Answer (score -2):

you need to make newS a char* and allocate space for it...

```
char *newS = malloc(strlen(sub) + 1);
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I want to append maximum of 50 characters to newS and print. There are solutions in C++ and JAVA. but no where I can find it for C.

Comment: I think you need to read a book on C instead of just trying to code in it with no understanding at all.

Comment: that's very kind of you. suggest me some book.

Comment: The C Primer is great, it will teach you the difference between char and char*... http://www.amazon.com/C-Primer-Plus-5th-Edition-ebook/dp/B0050G2RA0